# Select specified data from multiples tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database with 10 tables, each table contains :

```
id        name        level
```

The name of tables is : `table_01,table_02,table_03....table_10`.
Now, how to create the query to get all data from all this tables, with union ? Please help me, thx in advance
p.s. with condition `level = 10`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp check this out.

Comment: Use join to fetch data and each table has unique alias to table to avoid conflict in name of columns (each name table_01,table_02,table_03....table_10 etc)

Comment: `SELECT * from table_01 UNION SELECT * from table_02 .... SELECT * from table_10`

Comment: The answer is to have one table, with the columns id, name, level, t_id, where the new column t_id has the values 1 to 10 (depending on which table they were supposed to be in.) You can even create views v_01 to v_10.

Comment: UNION is fine, but if you really want to get all the Data then you must use UNION ALL like SELECT * FROM TABLE_01 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE_02 ...... UNION ALL SELECT * FROM TABLE_10. UNION ALL will show duplicate records also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id,name,level FROM table_01
UNION
SELECT id,name,level FROM table_02
UNION
SELECT id,name,level FROM table_03;
```

Similarly you can create for all other tables.